# Get peak value from analysing data stored in Azure Data Lake gen2

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-data-lake, azure-stream-analytics

I have following model:

```
Parameter
Value
```

I am sending it to Stream Analytics, which produces me change of Value based on value of Parameter. I am storing this output in Data Lake gen2 in following format:

```
Parameter
deltaValue = Value - LAG(Value)
```

How can I find value for Parameter, for which deltaValue is peaking? There are more parameters that impact this value change so this isn't always same delta for same parameter, but tendency should be clear for this particular parameter

Tools are not set in stone, if there is better tool feel free to suggest, as long it is Azure :)

Comment: Hi there, what is the time period to consider for your calculation. When you say "peaking", do you min the maximum over the last 30 minutes, 1h, etc? Or the overall max that ever happened? Can you also elaborate on why you are using Stream Analytics on the first place? Do you need real time calculations here? Is this some kind of alerting scenario?

Comment: It's a vehicle telemetry analysis - I am doing a run and after it I want to know optimal parameters. This case is braking analysis - braking efficiency peaks at given brake temperature, I want to know what is optimal range of temperatures based on deceleration vs temp. As mentioned before, tools not set in stone, but I thought stream is best because it does analyse on the fly.

Comment: You either want the optimal result on the full run, or a live analysis that can only give the best result so far as the run happens. This is unrelated to the tool you may want to use. It's physics: either you have the full data set (run is completed), or you don't (on the fly, you only have the past). You either want completeness, or low latency.

Comment: Stream processing engines like Azure Stream Analytics give you low latency. You define arbitrary rules to define partial completeness via time windows (give me the max value looking at the past hour, give me an average for the last 10 seconds...). It's good if you want to feed back parameters to your braking system in real time, depending on the telemetry it's emitting. It gets in the way if you're doing full runs to gather data and process the data offline. By gets in the way I mean that it will be expensive, and it will be cumbersome to look at the entire data set.

Comment: If you like SQL (and I suppose you do if you tried ASA), then I would load the entire dataset, post run, in a flavor of Azure SQL and do the analysis there. Synapse SQL Pool is good at ingesting files from blob/ADLS. If you prefer python or Scala, I would use Databricks notebooks. That's if the data is too big to fit in-memory on your workstation (10Gbs+). Less than that I would try a local SQL instance (SQL Server Developer Edition), Power BI Desktop or even Excel.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by [@FlorianEiden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633925/florian-eiden) in comment section, there are other many services in Azure which provide the features for different scenarios and you need to choose the best which suits your requirements.

You need to consider:

- You either want the optimal result on the full run, or a live analysis that can only give the best result so far as the run happens. This is unrelated to the tool you may want to use. It's physics: either you have the full data set (run is completed), or you don't (on the fly, you only have the past). You either want completeness, or low latency.
- Stream processing engines like Azure Stream Analytics give you low latency. You define arbitrary rules to define partial completeness via time windows (give me the max value looking at the past hour, give me an average for the last 10 seconds...). It's good if you want to feed back parameters to your braking system in real time, depending on the telemetry it's emitting. It gets in the way if you're doing full runs to gather data and process the data offline. By gets in the way I mean that it will be expensive, and it will be cumbersome to look at the entire data set.
- If you like SQL (and I suppose you do if you tried ASA), then I would load the entire dataset, post run, in a flavor of **Azure SQL** and do the analysis there. **Synapse SQL Pool** is good at ingesting files from blob/ADLS. If you prefer python or Scala, I would use **Databricks notebooks**. That's if the data is too big to fit in-memory on your workstation (10Gbs+). Less than that I would try a local SQL instance (SQL Server Developer Edition), Power BI Desktop or even Excel.